# Understanding repeated evaluation of template types/values

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-assert

I have the following code, and I do not understand why the last `!has_size<Bar>::value` evaluates to true only if I don't comment out the exact same `static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, ...)` prior to defining `Bar`

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class, class = void> struct has_size : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct has_size<
    T, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(T) > 0)>::type> 
    : std::true_type
{};

// expected success
struct Foo {};
static_assert( has_size<Foo>::value, "Foo doesn't have size");

struct Bar; // declare bar

// if we comment out this line, the static_assert below struct Bar{} fails
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size");    

struct Bar {};  // define bar

// why is this true now, but false if I comment out the previous assertion?
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size");
```

I want to make some templating decisions later based on the value of `has_size<Bar>`.  The behavior is the same across msvc, gcc, and clang.  I'm trying to figure out if this is intended and well-documented behavior, or if I'm wandering into UB land or some other calamity by relying on this behavior.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of class template instantiations as being "cached" or "memoized." More formally, class templates have [a single point of instantiation](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#point-8.sentence-2) per translation unit.

So when you write:

```
struct Bar;
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size");   // #1
struct Bar {};
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size");   // #2
```

`has_size<Bar>` is instantiated at `#1`. That is its *only* point of instantiation. At `#2`, we don't "redo" that calculation - so it is *still* false. If we did this again from a different translation unit, in a way that would give a different answer, that would be ill-formed (no diagnostic required), but in this situation - this is a well-formed program.

When you comment out `#1`, now the point of instantiation of `has_size<Bar>` becomes `#2`. And at *that* point in the program, `Bar` is complete, so `has_size<Bar>` is now `true_type`... so the static assertion triggers.

Answer (score 3):

Every complete type `T` in c++ has `sizeof(T)>0` or more simply `sizeof(T)` is a valid expression, `has_size` is using this to detect if some type is either complete of not and is doing it through [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

The first `static_assert`

```
struct Bar;
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size"); // (1)
```

causes the instantiation of `has_size<Bar>` which at the point it is instantiated `Bar` is not complete, this cause that the test `sizeof(T) > 0` in the second specialization of `has_size` fail, this failure resort in using the definition of the primary template `has_size : std::false_type` which satisfy `has_size<Bar>::value == false`.

When the second `static_assert`

```
struct Bar {};
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value, "Bar has a size"); // (2)
```

is evaluated, the specialization `has_size<Bar>` is requested again, but this time `Bar` is complete and there's already an instantiation for `has_size<Bar>` (the one that inherit from `std::false_type`), that specialization is used instead of instantiating a new one, thus still saying that `has_type<Bar>::value == false`.

When you comment the first `static_assert` (1), at the moment (2) is evaluated, `Bar` is already defined and now `sizeof(T) > 0` is valid and true, which select the specialization of `has_size<Bar> : std::true_type` and now it satisfy that `has_type<Bar>::value == true`.

No UB is involved.

---

In order to have a trait that reflect the change of completeness of a type `T`, you could go along with:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto has_size(int) -> decltype((void)sizeof(T), bool{})
{ return true; }

template <class T>
constexpr auto has_size(...) -> bool
{ return false; }

struct Bar;
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>(0), "Bar has a size");        
struct Bar {};  // define bar    
static_assert( !has_size<Bar>(0), "Bar has a size"); // fail
```

Comment: I think the questioner was really asking about why commenting out the first `static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value` causes the second `static_assert( !has_size<Bar>::value` to fail.

Comment: @jbapple is correct, I will clarify the question further.  I do like your simplification/workaround of the `has_size` method, however